# Can we have multiple serverless clouds in the same project?

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, architecture, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a very small doubt and it is not related to the coding but the architecture so any help would be great. I don't ask questions on Stack Overflow so please avoid if I did ask something wrong

Case:
I am building an application that will run on AWS Lambda as well as Azure Serverless. Is there any approach on how to reuse most of the development code in both the clouds

also, I am thinking to use their respective databases i.e AWS RDS and Azure Postgres. Will that be the right solution?

And I Have followed the article
[multicloud solutions azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/serverless/serverless-multicloud)

Comment: While it is an interesting question, unfortunately it is not fit for this particular forum as it is quite broad and will likely result in opinion-based answers. Please narrow it down to one specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Where should I ask this question? I can tag you there